# Using DB Links on a PL/SQL script throws "Table not found" error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, ora-00942

While trying to create a report using PL/SQL I'm finding myself stuck with the following problem, I created a SQL query that access 2 tables on a remote DB using a DB Link, running the query alone itself returns the expected results but when I run the very same query and put the results into a cursor I get a

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

error.

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the alias I'm using for each table or maybe the select statement is trying to select local tables, I don't know, do you have any suggestions?

PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR t_bug_details IS (SELECT h.*
  FROM table1@REMOTEDB h,
       table2@REMOTEDB rml
  WHERE h.product_id   IN (123)
  AND h.category       IN ('category')
  AND h.status          < 4
  AND h.status NOT     IN (1,2,3)
  AND h.release_status IN (upper('P'))
  --AND h.programmer     IN (upper('MRFOO'))
  AND h.some_id      = rml.some_id
  and rownum <=400);

REPORT_DAY VARCHAR2(40);
mail_html clob;
mail_bod clob;

BEGIN

FOR v_some_details in t_bug_details
LOOP
REPORT_DAY := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REPORT_DAY || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.reptnom || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.subject || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.field || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.release_status || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.status || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.category || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.sub_field || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.datef1 || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.field_by || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.programmer || '|' ||
                     TRUNC(sysdate - v_some_details.datef1) || '|' ||
                     TRUNC(sysdate - v_some_details.upd_date)|| '|' ||
                     v_some_details.fix_avail_date|| '|' ||
                     v_some_details.bug_type || '|' ||
                     v_some_details.base_reptnom);
END LOOP;

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NO RECORDS FOUND');
END;
```

Answer (score 5):

PL/SQL can run under different rights than SQL does.  I am guessing you have rights on these tables granted through a role, which your user can use but PL/SQL can't by default.  It is the difference between definer's rights and invoker's rights.  See [Oracle's documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same error with 10g.

1. It happened when I made a private DB link and got the ora-00942 error.
2. The user of the link is not the owner of the tables, but he is granted to access the
   tables
3. So, I changed the link to a public link - then everything worked
   fine.